# iPhone:How to prepare app build to my client for testing?

Tags: iphone

I am a registered Apple developer. I am developing an iPhone application for my client. If i want to give my app build to my client for testing my build, do i need to create a build using my adhoc provisioning profile and send the build as well as my adhoc provisioning profile to my client? If yes, how can they install my build on their iPhone devices?

Could someone guide me please?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to do an build with an adhoc provisioning profile.

Your client will need to drag the provisioning file to iTunes. I'm assuming you'll be emailing a ZIP file of the application package to the client. They should unzip it and drag the resulting folder on Windows or package on OS X to iTunes and sync their phone.